# Documents are marked as Executable

Tags: linux, debian, file-association

I decided to add a GUI to my Debian installation, and was kinda impressed. One issue I'm having though after adding KDE and XFCE is that double-clicking on .RTF files brings up the dialog, asking if I want to run it in the Terminal, or just run it.

[image]

I can still right-click the file and open it with other programs, but how would I set it to always open in, for example, Libre Office, by just double-clicking the file?

I tried removing the execute bit (big mistake!) from all my files, but that broke many other programs. I then put the Execute bit back to get everything working again, at least to how it was before. Therefore, I know that's not the proper method. This is affecting (so far) .RTF and .TXT files. .GIF, .PDF and .JPG files are opening in viewers properly. The files live on an EXT4 partition, inside my home folder.

Comment: No comment as to why it's a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horrible excuse, but I solved it!

I'm sure at some point, I did a `chmod 777 -R` on my entire home folder, for some reason or the other. I found that I can *selectively* unchoose the Execute bit, then double-clicking the file will open it with its default viewer.

Comment: `.doc` files open on double-click, whether they are set executable or not, while `.rtf` and `.txt` files bring up the dialogue you describe when executable. The difference is that executable text files could easily be shell scripts, for all the system can tell, whereas binary files have a "magic number" at the beginning to identify their file type. `.rtf` files are wholly text and start with `{\ `, but a shell script could start with this, hence the prompt if set executable. All text files present this problem, unless they start with `#!`, which then becomes a magic number for scripts.

Comment: To fix your /home perms from a chmod 777 you would want to do something like this.  `find /home -type d -print0 | xargs --null chmod 0750 ; find /home -type f -print0 | xargs --null chmod 0640`.

Comment: Except that will zap the execute bit from all regular files; you may have some which require it. The real lesson here is that **chmod 777 is extremely disruptive** and sometimes outright **dangerous**.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (and I presume the same for Debian, provided it uses Nautilus) you simply right-click on any `.rtf` file, choose **Properties**, and click on the **Open With** tab. This gives you a list of installed programs: choose the one you want and press **Set as default**.

You can also press **Add** to include it in the recommended program list: these appear on the **Open With** submenu when you right-click on the file.

Any changes apply to all files with the same name extension (all `.rtf` files, in this case): repeat for other extensions. Note that `.rtf` and `.RTF` are handled as separate extensions.

Comment: It already had LibreOffice Writer as the default program. I chose it again, hit OK, and the same results as before, asking if I want to execute it.